# Reason for hiccups?

Tags: zoology

I recently fed my axolotyl an earthworm, which is good for them. I was rather kind and made sure that the said earthworm was quickly despatched beforehand. Now, watching the axolotyl whilst swallowing the worm, he exhibited a series of rhythmic "hiccups". It got me thinking. Maybe hiccups are an ancient evolutionary means of ensuring that live prey are killed by the movements of the diaphragm muscle to protect the ingestor, whether the prey is eaten on purpose, or by error. Even herbivores may have hiccups because they may swallow, say a snake or something by accident. A horrible thought, I know, but it may make evolutionary sense ! Although I understand that only mammals have diaphragms, perhaps this is an evolutionary muscular trait which stems from a common anscestor which has been refined in animals. I would be very interested to hear anyone else's thoughts. Many thanks, Donna Skelly.

Comment: This [phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiccup) seems to be typical to mammals only.

Comment: Non-mammals don't have a diaphragm.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12539245), linked from the Wikipedia page that Sanjuka linked, suggests an older evolutionary role for hiccups, but I think this is all quite controversial and not well worked out. I'd also caution that hiccups are using machinery that exists for other purposes, so there might not be a great evolutionary reason or origin besides "it wasn't harmful enough to be selected against."